# Is it possible to build extra RC (remote-controlled) vehicles?

Tags: surviving-mars

Is it possible to build additional Rover, Explorer or Transport vehicles? if so, how?

I guess it's possible because of the research shared below, but I can't find how and it's not mentioned at this moment in the Encyclopedia from what I can see.

[image]

Comment: I know you can order some from space with your rockets, but making them....I haven't found anything just yet.  I'm currently watching the series for it.  I'm only on Episode 3.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NB6TQw7qwy8

Comment: @KevinFischer You should post it as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's deeper in the tech tree. Here's the tech choice to build a rover:

[image]